# Removing an anti-pattern from views to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models with a relation:

```
Company has_many :quotes
```

I want to remove an anti-pattern logic and place it in the controller:

```
<%= Quote.where(company_id: c.id).where(paid: true).count %>
```

The setup:

**Controller:**

```
@companies = Company.all
```

**Views:**

```
<% @companies.each do |c| %>
  <%= Quote.where(company_id: c.id).where(paid: true).count %>
<% end %>
```

I want to show total quotes for each company. While the above works, I do not want that logic in the views. How to put that in the controller?

**I have this in controller:**

```
...

@jobs_count = @companies.map do |c| Quote.where(company_id: c.id).where(paid:true) end

...
```

That does not work. The view page does not use params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Company.has_many :quotes` already allows you to use `company.quotes` rather than `Quote.where(company_id: company.id)`.

Now, define this scope on the `Quote` model:

```
class Quote
  scope :paid, -> { where paid: true }
  # ...
end
```

Now your view can say

```
<% @companies.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.quotes.paid.count %>
<% end %>
```

... with no need for any changes in the controller.

Does that look better?

Comment: Morning all! Both answers looks great. Which one is more easily maintainable?

Comment: I would add the `quote_count` method mainly for DRYness; that is, *if I were using it often.* Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

[PJSCopeland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1157242/pjscopeland) has made a great suggestion by using a named scope:

```
class Quote
  scope :paid, -> { where paid: true }
end
```

but I would suggest taking it a step further by keeping "quotes paid count" as a concern of your `Company` model:

```
class Company
  def quote_count
    quotes.paid.count
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @companies.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.quote_count %>
<% end %>
```

This also makes it easier to unit test you `Quote` and `Company` models.

Comment: Nice for the unit test. This looks easily customisable